# awk command while ((getline < "gpsoutput.tr") > 0 for constantly updating file contents

Tags: bash, awk, getline, nmea

I am currently using a G-STAR IV globalsat GPS which gives me the following output (which is coming from the GPS every 1 second) and I save this output by redirecting to a file name  "gpsoutput.tr". This file gets constantly updated each time it receives a GPS signal. The content of this file is as follows:

```
$GPGSV,3,2,10,14,43,184,,27,33,314,,29,21,152,,16,17,263,*7D
$GPGSV,3,3,10,24,10,092,,19,06,322,*79
$GPRMC,095827.000,A,2335.2440,N,05809.8432,E,0.55,103.38,091114,,,A*66
$GPGGA,095828.000,2335.2443,N,05809.8433,E,1,04,5.2,89.5,M,-34.7,M,,0000*46
$GPGSA,A,3,21,22,18,15,,,,,,,,,6.4,5.2,3.6*3C
$GPRMC,095828.000,A,2335.2443,N,05809.8433,E,1.21,102.44,091114,,,A*63
$GPGGA,095829.000,2335.2446,N,05809.8434,E,1,04,5.2,89.5,M,-34.7,M,,0000*45
$GPGSA,A,3,21,22,18,15,,,,,,,,,6.4,5.2,3.6*3C
$GPRMC,095829.000,A,2335.2446,N,05809.8434,E,0.92,102.44,091114,,,A*69
$GPGGA,095830.000,2335.2448,N,05809.8437,E,1,04,5.2,89.5,M,-34.7,M,,0000*40
$GPGSA,A,3,21,22,18,15,,,,,,,,,6.4,5.2,3.6*3C
$GPRMC,095830.000,A,2335.2448,N,05809.8437,E,1.25,102.12,091114,,,A*62
$GPGGA,095831.000,2335.2450,N,05809.8441,E,1,04,5.2,89.5,M,-34.7,M,,0000*49
$GPGSA,A,3,21,22,18,15,,,,,,,,,6.4,5.2,3.6*3C
$GPRMC,095831.000,A,2335.2450,N,05809.8441,E,1.47,101.80,091114,,,A*67
$GPGGA,095832.000,2335.2455,N,05809.8446,E,1,04,5.2,89.5,M,-34.7,M,,0000*48
$GPGSA,A,3,21,22,18,15,,,,,,,,,6.4,5.2,3.6*3C
$GPGSV,3,1,10,21,55,052,18,22,54,297,14,18,53,011,22,15,18,042,18*72
$GPGSV,3,2,10,14,43,184,,27,33,314,,29,21,152,,16,17,263,*7D
$GPGSV,3,3,10,24,10,092,,19,06,322,*79
$GPRMC,095832.000,A,2335.2455,N,05809.8446,E,2.36,100.07,091114,,,A*6D
```

this file ("gpsoutput.tr") keeps getting added with new lines each time it receives a GPS signal.

Now, I have a bash file which runs an awk program continuously to extracts the (speed), the (latitude, longitude) and the (UTC timestamp) in three different files. This is the bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Starting GPS info gathering"
while true; do
    awk -F, -f gpsgetinfo.awk gpsoutput.tr

 done
```

Finally, my awk program is very simple which I want it to constantly read the latest record from the gpsoutput.tr file and extract the above mentioned infos, in the three separate files. the awk program (gpsgetinfo.awk) is as follows:

```
BEGIN {
    FS = ","; 
    OFS = " ";

    while ((getline < "gpsoutput.tr") > 0) {


        if($1=="$GPRMC") {
                converted = $8*1.852; 
                printf $4 " " $6 "\n" >> "data1.txt";
                printf "%.3f \n", converted >> "speed.txt";
                printf $2 "\n" >> "gpstime.txt";
        }


    }
}


END {
    fflush();
}
```

The problem is, that in my output files(data1.txt, speed.txt and gpstime.txt) from the awk program, the same output is repeating several times and within a few seconds, the file size is reaching to the size of Mega bytes. To make it clear. this is how my utc time output file is:

```
095546.000
095547.000
095546.000
095547.000
095546.000
095547.000
095546.000
095547.000
095546.000
095547.000
095546.000
095547.000
095546.000
095547.000
095546.000
095547.000
095546.000
095547.000
095546.000
095547.000
095546.000
095547.000
095546.000
095547.000
095546.000
```

and it repeats for several 100 times in the file.

While the expected output in gpstime.tr should just be :

```
095546.000
095547.000
095548.000
095549.000
095550.000
095551.000
```

and so on.. since the gps signal is received every 1 second.

The gpsoutput.tr file where the nmea data is being saved, is just a few kbs, and without any recurrences in data.

Can anyone tell me . why the output files are having so many repeated values?  i have also tried using printf $4 " " $6 "\n" > "data1.txt"; (single '>' instead of '>>') but didn't work for me.

Comment: Why are you using the `getline` ??

Comment: because i want it to constantly read the most recent data received from GPS. Id there any other command that you could suggest?

Comment: Doesnt awk do that by default?. Try without using the while loop

Comment: No.. i have tried doing that.. unfortunately, awk works for static input data only.. with my gps output file getting constantly updated. tthe awk program did not work on it

Comment: You are getting more number of outputs because, by default the awk read line by line from the input file. in addition to that the getline causes a line read from the input file which doubles the expected output. in short am not sure if awk the something you want to use for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

The way to fix this depends on which version of awk you use.  First, simplify your awk program.

```
# gpsgetinfo.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = ","; 
    OFS = " ";
}
$1=="$GPRMC" {
    printf $4 " " $6 "\n" > "data1.txt"
    printf "%.3f \n", converted > "speed.txt"
    printf $2 "\n" > "gpstime.txt"

    fflush("")
}
```

Redirection within an awk program behaves a little differently than redirection in the shell. You *really* need to [read the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html). The redirection I used above might not be appropriate for your application.

**gawk**

```
$ tail -f gpsoutput.tr | awk -f gpsgetinfo.awk
```

**mawk**

On my own system, I use the full path to mawk.

```
$ tail -f gpsoutput.tr | /usr/bin/mawk -W interactive -f gpsgetinfo.awk
```